# error: 553 sorry, that domain isn't in my list of allowed rcpthosts

Tags: oracle, utl-mail

I want send the email from oracle database.

So I did the following steps

1. `@F:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\RDBMS\ADMIN\utlmail.sql`
2. `@F:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\RDBMS\ADMIN\prvtmail.plb`
3. `alter system set smtp_out_server = 'webmail.vilsoft.co.in:25' scope=both;`
4. ```
   exec utl_mail.send(sender=> 'Id1@vilsoft.co.in',
                      recipients=>'Id2@vilsoft.co.in',
                      subject=>'test mail',message=>'hi');
   ```

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

So the mail is send to Destination Correctly.

But When I want to send the mail from one server to another server So i execute the following query

```
SQL> exec utl_mail.send(sender=> 'ID1@vilsoft.co.in',recipients=>'Id2@gmail.com',
                        subject=>'test mail',message=>'hi');
```

then following error occurs....

```
BEGIN utl_mail.send(sender=> 'ID1@vilsoft.co.in',recipients=>'Id2@gmail.com',
                    subject=>'test mail',message=>'hi'); 
END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 553 sorry, that domain isn't in my list of
allowed rcpthosts (#5.7.1)

ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 20
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 98
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 240
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_MAIL", line 424
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_MAIL", line 594
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

So Please help me to resolve this error ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an Oracle error per se - Oracle is simply reporting back an error it received from the mail system. The error message itself (SMTP 553) can mean several things, among them that your ISP does not allow unauthenticated sending of mail outside your domain, or that your local network security policy does not allow mail to be sent from your mail server to addresses in the gmail.com domain, or that the mail server you're sending to sees your domain or address on a blacklist. Talk to your ISP to verify.